# Chrome Extension: Auto-start content script on load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, polling

After scouring SO, the Google Chrome Developer docs, and other websites... I'm still having a problem getting my content script to auto-start. Essentially, I need the content script to poll for div innerHtml every x seconds and send a message to the background.js script for further processing. Seems simple enough, but even with "run_at":"document_end" specified, it never starts. I suspect it's something trivial so I'm just looking for other sets of eyes to point me in the right direction. Also, it needs to run with no user interaction at all.

Here's my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension Name",
  "description": "Extension description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
    }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

my content.js file:

```
var pollInterval = 30000;
var timerId;

function startPoller() {
  var elementOfInterest = document.getElementById('id_of_interest');
  var content = elementOfInterest.innerHtml;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({payload: content});
  timerId = window.setTimeout(startPoller, pollInterval);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  startPoller();
});
```

and the bg.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  }
);
```

so it's pretty uninteresting. Help appreciated.

Comment: If you put `console.log` in your content script, can you see it logging to the console of a webpage?

Comment: in the content script file, add an event listener "on load"; also chage "document_end" to "document_start"

Comment: I've added a console.log('some static text') to the startPoller method but don't see anything

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener` instead of `document.addEventListener`.

Comment: If you set run_at to document_end you can just ditch event listener.

Comment: @Walk my original version had document_end w/ no event listener, but wasn't seeing anything in the web page console or the generated background page console.

Comment: The first thing to do is to debug the content script.  Set a breakpoint, then step through the code and see what happens. BTW the element may be added dynamically so you may want to delay the first run: setTimeout(startPoller, 5000)

Comment: @wOxxOm always a good idea. Turns out there was a syntax error in the polling method.

Answer (score 2):

The working code is below:

manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension Name",
  "description": "Extension description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
    }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

content.js file:

```
var pollInterval = 5000;
var timerId;

function startPoller() {
  try {
    console.log('startPoller called');
    var elementOfInterest = document.getElementById('nav_home');
    if (elementOfInterest !== undefined && elementOfInterest !== null) {
      var content = elementOfInterest.innerHTML;
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({payload: content});
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  timerId = window.setTimeout(startPoller, pollInterval);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.log('window.addEventListener');
  startPoller();
});
```

bg.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  }
);
```

Thanks for your eyeballs, folks